# Why isn't the class MediaPlayer instantiated using new keyword

Tags: java, android

I am looking at some tutorials for Android development and I saw the case below

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.id.song)
```

My question is the following: Why isn't there a "new" keyword involved when creating a new MediaPlayer object? I thought that new has to be used anytime you create a instance of class

So what if I do

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
mp.create(this, R.id.song);
```

is this wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong. I explained the reason in my solution.

Comment: This sort of thing is relatively commonplace when dealing with SPI type classes such as Runtime, Toolkit, DocumentBuilderFactory and so forth.  Using a static factory method allows the user to not tie themselves to a particular implementation.  Or in the case of Toolkit, you could be using the standard toolkit for the platform yo are on, or maybe a headless toolkit.  In this particular case, it seems like it's just a style choice by the API author.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is the following: Why isn't there a "new" keyword involved when creating a new MediaPlayer object?

Well you're calling a static method which will (presumably) create a new instance.

Maybe that method calls the constructor directly - or maybe it creates an instance of some subclass. Or maybe it returns a reference to an existing instance instead.

That's the nice thing about factory methods - they get to hide their implementation details :)

Comment: this is indeed the case, the documentation calls it a "convenience method" http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: So what if I do MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); mp.create(this, R.id.song); is this wrong?

Comment: @dido Your second call will do nothing as you don't save the result. If you save the result `mp = mp.create(this, R.id.song)` you will overwrite and discard the result from the call to the constructor so while not technically wrong it is pointless. (Plus the IDE and/or the compiler will warn you that `create` is a static method and should be called in a static context, i.e. from the class and not from an object.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a "factory"-function. Internally it calls `new MediaPlayer()`, you just do not see it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually allowed to call *new* on a MediaPlayer.

The following is taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

> When a MediaPlayer object is just created using new or after reset() is called, it is in the Idle state [...] Furthermore, the MediaPlayer objects created using new is in the Idle state, while those created with one of the overloaded convenient create methods are NOT in the Idle state. In fact, the objects are in the Prepared state if the creation using create method is successful.

Basically using new vs the static method just changes what state your MediaPlayer is in. If you new one, then you'll have to initialize it with setDataSource() and prepare it with onPrepare(). Where as your all ready to go with the static helper.